# Simplest way to add drop-down selection to search box (hidden) without javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress, forms

I'm using a WordPress theme and have a search box.

Before the search box appears, the user has to select a category from a dropdown list.

Once the user selects their category, they can then search by keyword within that category, using the search box.

My problem is, whatever keyword they type in, it searches the WHOLE website i.e. domain.com?s=keyword

I'm a beginner, so I thought the easiest way for me is to append the category name to the search, along with their keyword once they select it i.e. domain.com?s=keyword+category

I just don't know how to do this within the form.

Javascript/JQuery is too complex for me :(

Any ideas?

Comment: To get started with jQuery you can view [this sample code](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/) to how to create a autocomplete search box.

Comment: Isn't quite what I'm looking for but I came across an onSubmit function... maybe that can add the selected option to the end of the search??

Comment: Can you show us your code?

Comment: Are you looking for the client side solution? I mean, does your server side already supports searching over a category?